# UPDATE JOIN with WHERE parameters

Tags: sql, database, join, sql-update

Fairly new to SQL, so I'm sure I'm missing something fairly fundamental. That said, everything I'm seeing online tells me this is right, but it's not working for me.

```
UPDATE contact  
 SET cellphone = '4383991212' 
 FROM contact
 LEFT JOIN employee ON contact.id = employee.id 
 WHERE employee.fname = 'Susan' AND employee.lname = 'Shepard';
```

I'm getting this error:

> SyntaxError: Parse error on line 61: ...one = '4383991212' FROM
> contact LEFT J ----------------------^ Expecting 'EOF', 'COMMA',
> 'RPAR', 'IN', 'LIKE', 'ARROW', 'DOT', 'CARET', 'EQ', 'WHERE', 'SLASH',
> 'EXCLAMATION', 'MODULO', 'GT', 'LT', 'GTGT', 'LTLT', 'NOT', 'AND',
> 'OR', 'PLUS', 'STAR', 'END', 'WHEN', 'ELSE', 'REGEXP', 'TILDA',
> 'GLOB', 'NOT_LIKE', 'BARBAR', 'MINUS', 'AMPERSAND', 'BAR', 'GE', 'LE',
> 'EQEQ', 'EQEQEQ', 'NE', 'NEEQEQ', 'NEEQEQEQ', 'BETWEEN',
> 'NOT_BETWEEN', 'IS', 'DOUBLECOLON', 'OUTPUT', 'GO', 'SEMICOLON', got
> 'FROM'

I'm at a loss. Can I get any help?

I have tried `INNER, LEFT, and FULL JOINs`. I have tried moving the SET around. The issue seems to always arise after the phone number.

Comment: Syntax varies by vendor and version.  Please specify which DBMS you're using (update question tags).

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE c 
SET cellphone = '4383991212'
FROM contact c
INNER JOIN employee e ON c.id = e.id
WHERE e.fname = 'Susan' AND e.lname = 'Shepard';
```

Try this: It sets the table alias appropriately, and the inner join should be what you are trying to achieve there

Comment: Its worked like a charm.. good answer.. Thank u